# Unable to add/edit a Server Object Extension

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, c#, deployment, server-object-extension

I have a C# project that creates a **SOE for ArcGIS Server 10.2.2**.  I build it in Visual Studio Express 2010 and am rewarded with `MyPitaExtension.soe`.  The contents of that file are what I expect (`Config.xml` alongside an `"Install"` folder containing `MyPitaExtension.dll` & `MyPitaExtension.pdb`).

I go to the `ArcGIS Server Manager > Sites > Extensions`, and try to add/edit the SOE (in some instances it is already installed; in others it is not).
In the dialog, I choose `MyPitaExtension.soe` and click `Add` or `Save`.  The dialog remains open and displays text below the Save/Cancel buttons that fits the format:

> fjsontoken[Big ugly thing that runs off the available space]

Clicking `Add` or `Save` again adds an identical string to the bottom of the dialog.
I've tried googling various combinations of 'fjsontoken', 'esri', 'soe', etc... but all I've found was [this very recent post about Portal](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/185685-error-when-adding-item-to-my-content-in-portal).
 I am a member of the Administrator role.

Has anyone had any luck diagnosing & fixing this?

**UPDATE 1:** A coworker (also in an Admin) gets the same results as I do.

**UPDATE 2:** I get the same results when adding NetSimpleRESTSOE.soe pre-packaged with the ArcObjects SDK. I'm now confident that this is a problem with our server configuration rather than a problem with the SOE itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geonet post linked above contains an answer that I just plain missed (I've been trying to cut back on my caffiene).  That answer referenced [a known bug](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2016/09/20/announcement-errors-encountered-in-arcgis-for-server-and-portal-for-arcgis-web-apps-after-certain-browser-updates/).  The way to avoid this is to use MSIE when uploading SOE files.  I used Chrome and my coworker used firefox.

**UPDATE:** At least in v10.4.1, MSIE is also required for creating new data stores.  Also there appears to be a [patch](http://support.esri.com/Products/Enterprise/arcgis-server/ArcGIS-GIS-Server/10-4-1#downloads?id=7449) for this now (which is already behind Chrome's latest release).